# html security trimming based on oauth

Tags: oauth, flask

I am building a web application using flask. I have also integrated oauth (google) into the application for authentication. I would like to know is it possible to security trim the elements of the html (menu items etc) based on your account details, post login ?

Comment: Can we get a snippet at your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically do this by adding "roles" to your user database.

Each user gets assigned a role, and that determines what he/she can do or see when they connect to your site. Example roles could be "Administrator", "Moderator" and "User", in order of decreasing power.

Once a user logs in to your application you can check `current_user.role`, both in view functions and in templates to determine what to show and what not to.